# Python - Web scraping - URL Protected by Kerberos HTTP SPNEGO

Tags: python, hadoop, web-scraping, kerberos, cloudera

I guys,

I have a script that test if the URL is accessible or not. The script use the module requests and requests_kerberos.

For a specific Website - that gives me some detail about my Hadoop Cluster - that always return the same message:

```
HTTP Status: 401 

401
```

I know that I have to make some configurations since this URL is protected by Kerberos.

For example, to have access using Firefox I had to follow these steps on Cloudera documentation:

```
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_sg_browser_access_kerberos_protected_url.html
```

How can I apply this using Python script? There exists any module that allows me to pass this authentication issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Google for `python SPNego` and have fun...

Comment: Save yourself a lot of heartache and use `curl` instead.

Comment: with curl I get 'requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='HOSTNAME', port=8090): Max retries exceeded with url: /cluster/nodes (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))' as a error message